# Matching alias template as template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer

Consider the [following code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XjObkCwtvrkB3Y7R):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<template<class...> class T, class... U>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type{};

template<template<class...> class T, class... U>
struct is_specialization_of<T, T<U...>> : std::true_type{};

template<class T, class U = int>
struct test{};

// (1) ok
static_assert(is_specialization_of<test, test<int>>::value, "1");

template<class T>
using alias = test<T>;

// (2) fails
static_assert(is_specialization_of<alias, alias<int>>::value, "2");

int main()
{
}
```

Why does (2), i.e. `static_assert` that uses alias template, fail?

How does the template argument deduction process in (2) differ from the one in (1)?

Comment: [CWG 1286](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [CWG issue 1286](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286). The question is: are `alias` and `test` equivalent? There used to be an example in [temp.type] which suggested that `y` and `z` have the same type here:

> ```
> template<template<class> class TT> struct X { };
> template<class> struct Y { };
> template<class T> using Z = Y<T>;
> X<Y> y;
> X<Z> z;
> ```

The example was corrected as part of [CWG defect 1244](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1244) - which indicated correctly that there is no wording in [[temp.alias]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.alias) that actually specifies that alias templates are equivalent to the templates they alias. The only wording there refers to equivalence of alias template specializations:

> When a *template-id* refers to the **specialization of an alias template**, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by substitution of its *template-arguments* for the *template-parameters* in the *type-id* of the alias template.

The intent is apparently that `y` and `z` *do* have the same type in this example, meaning that `Z` and `Y` are actually equivalent. But unless and until the wording in the resolution is adopted, they are not. Today, `alias` and `test` are *not* equivalent but `alias<int>` and `test<int>` *are*. This means that `is_specialization_of<alias, alias<int>>` is `is_specialization_of<alias, test<int>>`, where `alias` is unique from `test`, which would not match your partial specialization and thus be `false_type`.

Moreover, even with the adoption of the wording in #1286, `test` and `alias` are *still not equivalent* for the obvious reason that `test` takes two template parameters and alias takes one template parameter. The example in the resolution wording mimics your example and clarifies the intent here:

> ```
> template<typename T, U = T> struct A;
>
> // ...
>
> template<typename V>   
>   using D = A<V>;      // not equivalent to A:
>                        // different number of parameters
> ```

Comment: Interestingly, if we change `test` to get a single template argument, then (2) still does not compile with any Clang and with GCC < 4.9. It means that GCC >= 4.9 already implements  #1286.

Comment: @IgorR. Well, 1286 isn't adopted. So it's arguably incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I think that name of alias template without template arguments list is not equivalent to the name of associated type. Because standard specifies only one such situation:

> 14.5.7 Alias templates [temp.alias]
>
> 2. When a template-id refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type
>      obtained by substitution of its template-arguments for the template-parameters in the type-id of the alias
>      template. [Note: An alias template name is never deduced.—end note ]

and this [works fine](http://ideone.com/uzkBl6):

```
static_assert(is_specialization_of<test, alias<int>>::value, "2");
```

Comment: Then, why if we remove `test`'s second template argument `U`, everything compiles well?

Comment: Is it because, "An alias template name is never deduced".  A partial specialization is chosen by attempting to deduce the specialization's parameters.  When the compiler is attempting to deduce `T` in the specialization, it doesn't consider `alias` as a possibility?

Comment: This is actually 17.5.7 now, after [this](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/ec4ca6fc07907ea817152970c45d4c04c86d3c5c); please use permanent names, i.e. [temp.alias] in this case. (That has the upside of being linkable to: [http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.alias](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.alias).)